# Call DLL with unsigned char* field from .NET Application

Tags: c, .net, unsigned

I am using a DLL built in C in my .NET application.
This DLL has a function with an unsigned char* input parameter

*short function_dll (unsigned char* data)*

I've looking for the best calling conversion for this parameter in .NET:
StringBuilder
char[]
byte[]

The call to the function works but randomly it fails with the error :
*Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt* no matter the conversion used.

This is the last thing I have tried after a lot of combinations but ... the problem persists, randomly the error arises.

***[DllImport(@"myDLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]***

***public static extern short function_dll([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] char[] data);***

Any idea?
Better conversion?

Thank you in advance,
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, the C# `char` is twice as large as the C++ one, so the monstrosity with the `char[]` is not going to work.

The question you should be asking yourself is this: is the string you're passing an input to the C++ function or an output?

If it's an input (ie you give the function a string and it doesn't modify it), the declaration should look like this:

```
[DllImport(@"myDLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern short function_dll([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string data);

// called like: function_dll("meep");
```

If the function you're passing is an output (ie you supply the function a buffer to write into), then the API you're working with is completely borked, because it doesn't take the length of the buffer as a parameter. Using the borked API then would use a `StringBuilder` with a preallocated buffer size of your choice and some hopes and prayers:

```
[DllImport(@"myDLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern short function_dll([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] StringBuilder data);

// called like: 
//   var sb = new StringBuilder(100);
//   function_dll(sb);
```

Comment: The parameter is an input. I tried both options you gave to me and the function doesn't work, there is no exception but it doesn't make what's expected. When using my solution (changing char[] for byte[]) it works. I have requested the source code of the DLL to see what's inside and see why it happens. Thank you!

Comment: Try changing the import attribute to `[DllImport("myDLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]`